# tortoiseCVS how to tell tag from branch

Tags: tags, branch, tortoisecvs

I have a dummy question. 
I have so many tags in cvs 
Now I am not sure which ones are real branches which ones are simply tags.

Thanks

Comment: I never used CVS I'm using SVN and in SVN I think that every tag in bound to a specific revision of some branch or trunk. Anyway I advise you to switch to GIT or at least SVN for your version control.

Comment: thanks. We are thinking to switch to git. but not yet. Currently I have so many tags and a few branches, I want to merge but first need figure out what branches exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select any one file in CVS, right click History, then tortoiseCVS gives a list of history including all tags and branches.
The tags are in yellow background, branches are in green background.

Also the icons for tags are different from branches on the history window.

Tag icon is a curve arrow within a square, while branch icon is two-overlapped dog-eared pages.